# React native app crash on apk launch after using realm

Tags: android, react-native, crash, realm, launch

I have a react native app using realm for saving user json input to device storage, then send the json data to api when they have stable connection (not automatically).

**It works perfectly when used in debugging mode**, but when I build it to apk and install to android device (the same one used for debugging), it crashes instantly without even showing the splash screen.

dependencies :

```
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.7",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.1",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "immer": "^9.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^2.8.2",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^3.1.5",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.40.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.35.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-material-buttons": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-material-ripple": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "realm": "10.19.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-offline": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
```

I'm stuck with this for two days now.
Found some similar issues and have try this approaches :

1. Use v10.20.0-beta.5 -> can't even launch in debugging
2. Removing react-native-reanimated
3. Disable hermes (never enabled in the first place)
4. add this to defaultConfig inside android/app/build.gradle :

```
ndk {
 abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
}
```

But nothing fixes the crash.

*I can't use AsyncStorage because of the 1MB cursor limit, and I will need to save maximum of 60MB. And I'm holding react native upgrade to 0.69 for now, because of the project's time limit.

How can I run the apk without crashing?

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: While posting dependencies may be helpful, posting the code that's crashing is kinda a requirement if you want help. The question is marked as Realm but your question states *is there any alternatives for saving large json data in user's device* which is not related to Realm, and generally speaking there are no issues saving large files to local storage. Perhaps if you can clarify the issue and include the code that's causing issues, along with your troubleshooting we may be able to help.

Comment: Yeah, but the code have no problem on debugging mode (in virtual device and real device). The issue only start when the apk is built and installed, then the app won't launch at all. So i'm guessing it's a dependency compatibility problem.

Comment: I understand you're looking for an answer but there are too many variables and the issue still isn't clear. For example: *I can't use AsyncStorage because of the 1MB cursor limit* - so, if you going beyond that limit then you're exceeded that requirement, right? Are you? What does *will need to save maximum of 60MB* mean exactly? If you writing 60Mb to a Realm object property, well, that's not going to work either as properties are limited to 15Mb. See what I mean? Too many things that *could* be the issue or a related issue - even on top of a potential dependency issue.

Comment: Have you created a fresh project with no code and started adding in dependencies one at a time until it breaks? Start with Realm (since it was tagged). Does it build & run? Yes, Add another and try building again. Keep going until it doesn't build and/or crashes. If you add all of them and it works, then you've got a coding issue in the original app so you will need to troubleshoot that.

Comment: Got it, I'll try with the fresh project, Thanks @Jay !